# Angular post and web api C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've tried to make a contact page using AngularJS and C# controller using Web Api.

I am working on it all the last week without find the correct answer that suits me.

I tried also post thru AJAX, JQUERY and angular.

Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost, AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ContactUs")]
    public void Post(ContactUsProperties EmailDetails)
    {
        //Code for sending email to the website owner...
    }
```

Angular JS Code:

```
app.controller("ContactController", function ($scope, $http) {



$scope.EmailDetails = {
    Phone: null,
    Email: null,
    Name: null,
    Subject: null,
    Body: null
};

$scope.EmailDetailsArr = [
    $scope.Phone,
    $scope.Email,
    $scope.Name,
    $scope.Subject,
    $scope.Body
];

$scope.EmailDetails = {
    Phone: $scope.Phone,
    Email: $scope.Email,
    Name: $scope.Name,
    Subject: $scope.Subject,
    Body: $scope.Body
};
$scope.CreateEmail = function () {

    console.log($scope.EmailDetails);
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.EmailDetails));

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/ContactUs',
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.EmailDetail)
    });
}
```

The routing is working, I know it cause the debugger stops me everytime I click on "Send" button. I tried it as an array, as JSON, as XML, as Everything and the object is still null!, I tried with [FROMBODY] still none.

I will be honest that if it POST require change of Web Api Config so I didn't change..

Please Guys Help Me Solve This Out, Explain Will Accept Happily.
Thanks :)

Comment: try this => url : '/ContactUs/Post'

Comment: Can you tell us what it is you expect your code to do?

Comment: There is no need to stringify the data. The [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) will automatically do that.

Comment: imgprasad --> the route is /ContactUs .. it works cause in visual studio debugger stop the running..            Hintham --> i try to send object to controller with details about the contact (the body, subject, and private details to reply him by phone or email and then name)

Comment: georgeawg --> didn't know that Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[FromBody]` in order to got [Parameter Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header
>   to select a formatter.

In this example, the content type is `application/json`.

```
public void Post([FromBody] ContactUsProperties EmailDetails)
```

Comment: I read about it and its saying about getting simple parameter, I want to transfer object that contains few strings in it and not 1 string. regardless to what I have read, I tried that and it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/ContactUs',
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.EmailDetail) <-- you are missing an 's' at the end
});
```

Comment: The object is still null